# CookieAuthenticator restlet

Tags: cookies, restlet-2.0, form-authentication

I have built some RESTful api's with REstlet 2.3.4.  I've been using HTTP_BASIC which let the browser prompt for credentials but it's time for a proper login form.  I figure the easiest way to implement this is CookieAuthenticator.  I can't find full working examples on github/google. I am sure i'm over looking them can someone provide a working example implementing CookieAuthenticator in Restlet?

Answer (score 0):

I did get this to work after all.  I have a longer answer [here](http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/CookieAuthenticator-for-Restlet-2-3-4-td7579386.html) with some code examples.  First, i was missing the fact that CookieAuthenticator is a filter and HAS the logic to handle login and logout.  You need to create EMPTY ServerResources with a method annotated with @Post that has nothing in the body.  Second, extend CookieAuthenticator and overwrite isLoggingIn(..) and isLoggingOut(..) with the code found in the link.

Cheers,
-ray

Comment: Hi Ray, to my mind, you should not have to create empty server resources. I wonder if there is a bug or something unclear. We'll keep you informed.